# Java Json formating not wokring ok

Tags: json, java

I have a program which read a csv file (1.2 mil) records, and then using batches , sent a json request to marketing cloud to create records.

The right format(working ) format of json is

```
[{
    "keys": {
        "Consumer": "S001"
    },
    "values": {
        "Consumer": "S001",
        "DateCreated": "10-08-18",
        "DateModified": "10-08-18",
        "EmailAddress": "sdautpure@appirio.com",
        "FirstName": "ShekharS001",
        "LastName": "Dautpure",
        "City": "Pune",
        "StateorProvince": "Maharashtra",
        "ZiporPostalCode": "2456AS",
        "Country": "India",
        "Title": "Sr",
        "Salutation": "Sr",
        "Language": "EN",
        "Gender": "1",
        "Age": "36",
        "CONFIRMED_AGE": "36",
        "MARITAL_STATUS": "Married",
        "DoubleOptin": "0",
        "OPTED_OUT": "0",
        "Locale": "nl_NL",
        "AddressHouseNumber": "580",
        "AddressStreetName": "Vuurvlindersingel",
        "PHONE_NUMBER": "",
        "PHONE_OPT_IN": "",
        "COUNTRY_DIAL_CODE": "",
        "MobilePhone": "",
        "PURLName": "",
        "PURL_Name_Default_Hypersite": "",
        "Deceased": "",
        "OriginSourceSystemID": "",
        "OriginSourceSystemName": "",
        "LastUpdatedSourceID": "",
        "LastUpdatedSourceCategoryName": "",
        "LastUpdatedDateJanrain": "",
        "LastUpdatedSourceName": "",
        "SubSourceSystemCode": "",
        "StrikeIronEmailValidation": "",
        "StrikeIronEmailValidationTimestamp": "",
        "EloquaContactID": "",
        "JanrainUserUUID": "S001",
        "DateCreatedinJanrain": "",
        "DATE_TIME_OF_CREATION_RCDH": "",
        "DATE_TIME_LAST_SOURCE_CHANGE_RCDH": "",
        "Synched with RCDH": "",
        "RCDH_NEW_CONSUMER_ID": "",
        "DateOfBirth": "",
        "SynchedwithJanrain": ""
    }
}, ...
]
```

However my java program is generating a bit different json message which is not working. How can Ichange the program so that correct json can be generated?

This is what my program is generating :

```
{
"keys": "{ Consumer: JanrainUserUUID }",
"values": [{
        "Locale": "Locale",
        "MARITAL_STATUS": "MARITAL_STATUS",
        "DateCreatedinJanrain": "DateCreatedinJanrain",
        "Gender": "Gender",
        "MobilePhone": "MobilePhone",
        "Consumer": "Consumer",
        "SynchedwithJanrain": "SynchedwithJanrain",
        "Synched with RCDH": "Synched with RCDH",
        "DateOfBirth": "DateOfBirth",
        "Address Type": "Address Type",
        "COUNTRY_DIAL_CODE": "COUNTRY_DIAL_CODE",
        "DATE_TIME_OF_CREATION_RCDH": "DATE_TIME_OF_CREATION_RCDH",
        "DoubleOptinTimestamp": "DoubleOptinTimestamp",
        "City": "City",
        "LastUpdatedSourceCategoryName": "LastUpdatedSourceCategoryName",
        "EmailAddress": "EmailAddress",
        "CONFIRMED_AGE_TIMESTAMP": "CONFIRMED_AGE_TIMESTAMP",
        "CONFIRMED_AGE": "CONFIRMED_AGE",
        "JanrainUserUUID": "JanrainUserUUID",
        "StateorProvince": "StateorProvince",
        "StrikeIronEmailValidationTimestamp": "StrikeIronEmailValidationTimestamp",
        "Country": "Country",
        "PHONE_OPT_IN": "PHONE_OPT_IN",
        "PURLName": "PURLName",
        "LastName": "LastName",
        "AddressStreetName": "AddressStreetName",
        "PHONE_NUMBER": "PHONE_NUMBER",
        "DoubleOptin": "DoubleOptin",
        "EloquaContactID": "EloquaContactID",
        "PURL_Name_Default_Hypersite": "PURL_Name_Default_Hypersite",
        "Deceased": "Deceased",
        "DateCreated": "DateCreated",
        "Salutation": "Salutation",
        "OriginSourceSystemID": "OriginSourceSystemID",
        "OPTED_OUT": "OPTED_OUT",
        "LastUpdatedSourceID": "LastUpdatedSourceID",
        "Language": "Language",
        "StrikeIronEmailValidation": "StrikeIronEmailValidation",
        "DATE_TIME_LAST_SOURCE_CHANGE_RCDH": "DATE_TIME_LAST_SOURCE_CHANGE_RCDH",
        "Age": "Age",
        "ZiporPostalCode": "ZiporPostalCode",
        "FirstName": "FirstName",
        "Title": "Title",
        "SubSourceSystemCode": "SubSourceSystemCode",
        "OriginSourceSystemName": "OriginSourceSystemName",
        "LastUpdatedSourceName": "LastUpdatedSourceName",
        "DateModified": "DateModified",
        "OPTED_OUT_TIMESTAMP": "OPTED_OUT_TIMESTAMP",
        "AddressHouseNumber": "AddressHouseNumber",
        "LastUpdatedDateJanrain": "LastUpdatedDateJanrain"
    }
]
}, ...
```

The flow of logic is:

1. TestMCBulkAsync --> Read the CSV and sent a batch of 200 record to CreatePayload
2. CreatePayload --> has the task of creating the json message for sending to MC

TestMCBulkAsync:

```
package marketingcloud;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException;

public class TestMCBulkAsync {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnirestException 
    {
        String ClientId = "AAAAAAAAAAAAA";
        String ClientSercet = "BBBBBBBBBBB";
        Integer BatchSize = 200;

        GetMCAccessToken mct = new GetMCAccessToken();
        String MCToken = mct.RetriveToken(ClientId, ClientSercet);

        BufferedReader crunchifyBuffer = null;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Consumer = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        try {
            String crunchifyLine;
            crunchifyBuffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\Works\\java\\AAAAAA\\Assets\\Consumer.csv"));


            // How to read file in java line by line?
            int ii=0;
            while ((crunchifyLine = crunchifyBuffer.readLine()) != null) 
            {               
                ArrayList<String> ABC = crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(crunchifyLine); 
                if(ii<BatchSize) 
                {
                    Consumer.add(ABC);
                    ii=ii+1;
                }else
                {
                    new CreatePayload(Consumer,BatchSize);

                    //Reseting the loop
                    ii=0;
                    Consumer.clear();
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (crunchifyBuffer != null) crunchifyBuffer.close();
            } catch (IOException crunchifyException) {
                crunchifyException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> crunchifyCSVtoArrayList(String crunchifyCSV) 
    {
        ArrayList<String> crunchifyResult = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (crunchifyCSV != null) {
            String[] splitData = crunchifyCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*");
            for (int i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                if (!(splitData[i] == null) || !(splitData[i].length() == 0)) {
                    crunchifyResult.add(splitData[i].trim());
                }
            }
        }

        return crunchifyResult;
    }

}
```

CreatePayload:

```
package marketingcloud;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class CreatePayload 
{
    public CreatePayload(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Consumerpayload,int batchsize)
    {
        String message = "";
        for (int ii=0;ii<=batchsize;ii++)
        {

            ArrayList<String> Con = new ArrayList<String>();
            Con=Consumerpayload.get(ii);

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
            json.put("keys", '{'+ " Consumer: "+Con.get(44)+" }");

            JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
            JSONObject item = new JSONObject();

            item.put("Consumer",Con.get(0));
            item.put("DateCreated",Con.get(1));
            item.put("DateModified",Con.get(2));
            item.put("EmailAddress",Con.get(3));
            item.put("FirstName",Con.get(4));
            item.put("LastName",Con.get(5));
            item.put("City",Con.get(6));
            item.put("StateorProvince",Con.get(7));
            item.put("ZiporPostalCode",Con.get(8));
            item.put("Country",Con.get(9));
            item.put("Title",Con.get(10));
            item.put("Salutation",Con.get(11));
            item.put("Language",Con.get(12));
            item.put("Gender",Con.get(13));
            item.put("DateOfBirth",Con.get(14));
            item.put("Age",Con.get(15));
            item.put("CONFIRMED_AGE",Con.get(16));
            item.put("CONFIRMED_AGE_TIMESTAMP",Con.get(17));
            item.put("MARITAL_STATUS",Con.get(18));
            item.put("DoubleOptin",Con.get(19));
            item.put("DoubleOptinTimestamp",Con.get(20));
            item.put("OPTED_OUT",Con.get(21));
            item.put("OPTED_OUT_TIMESTAMP",Con.get(22));
            item.put("Locale",Con.get(23));
            item.put("Address Type",Con.get(24));
            item.put("AddressHouseNumber",Con.get(25));
            item.put("AddressStreetName",Con.get(26));
            item.put("PHONE_NUMBER",Con.get(27));
            item.put("PHONE_OPT_IN",Con.get(28));
            item.put("COUNTRY_DIAL_CODE",Con.get(29));
            item.put("MobilePhone",Con.get(30));
            item.put("PURLName",Con.get(31));
            item.put("PURL_Name_Default_Hypersite",Con.get(32));
            item.put("Deceased",Con.get(33));
            item.put("OriginSourceSystemID",Con.get(34));
            item.put("OriginSourceSystemName",Con.get(35));
            item.put("LastUpdatedSourceID",Con.get(36));
            item.put("LastUpdatedSourceCategoryName",Con.get(37));
            item.put("LastUpdatedDateJanrain",Con.get(38));
            item.put("LastUpdatedSourceName",Con.get(39));
            item.put("SubSourceSystemCode",Con.get(40));
            item.put("StrikeIronEmailValidation",Con.get(41));
            item.put("StrikeIronEmailValidationTimestamp",Con.get(42));
            item.put("EloquaContactID",Con.get(43));
            item.put("JanrainUserUUID",Con.get(44));
            item.put("DateCreatedinJanrain",Con.get(45));
            item.put("SynchedwithJanrain",Con.get(46));
            item.put("DATE_TIME_OF_CREATION_RCDH",Con.get(47));
            item.put("DATE_TIME_LAST_SOURCE_CHANGE_RCDH",Con.get(48));
            item.put("Synched with RCDH",Con.get(49));
//          item.put("RCDH_NEW_CONSUMER_ID",Con.get(50));
            array.put(item);
            json.put("values", array);
            if(ii==0)
            {
                message=json.toString();
            }else {
            message = message +","+json.toString();}
            System.out.println(message);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Apologies for lengthy question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonObject.html) includes this example that you should follow:

```
 JsonObject value = Json.createObjectBuilder()
     .add("firstName", "John")
     .add("lastName", "Smith")
     .add("age", 25)
     .add("address", Json.createObjectBuilder()
         .add("streetAddress", "21 2nd Street")
         .add("city", "New York")
         .add("state", "NY")
         .add("postalCode", "10021"))
     .add("phoneNumber", Json.createArrayBuilder()
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "home")
             .add("number", "212 555-1234"))
         .add(Json.createObjectBuilder()
             .add("type", "fax")
             .add("number", "646 555-4567")))
     .build();
```

You are using `put` from the underlying `Map` type that does not correctly escape the values.

Note that it would be better to ask this question on a Java forum such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I have salesforce url in cache and i didnt realise it . my applogies on it

Comment: Yes, the last paragraph is most important here. There are few Java experts on SFSE. Probably hundreds or thousands of times more relevant expertise on [so].